# Why CSS sets a different computed style to width and margin when using mm units?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, units-of-measurement

Changing a visible node's style width *or* marginLeft to `10px` gives the same computed style: 10px.

However, on several navigators, it gives different results with `1mm`.

Why ?

I ran this code:

```js
const d = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
d.style.marginLeft = d.style.width = '1mm';
const cs = window.getComputedStyle(d);
console.log(cs.width, cs.marginLeft);
```

and it gave these results:

| property | chrome 111 | firefox 111 | webkitgtk 2.40 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| width | 3.76562px | 3.78333px | 3.765625px |
| marginLeft | 3.77953px | 3.77953px | 3.779528px |

Comment: Because there is no relation between distance (mm) and amount of pixels, the browser will give any answer it likes ;-)

Comment: These are actually some really interesting numbers.  CSS defines 1px as 1/96th of an inch.  There are 2.54 cm in an inch, and 10 millimeters in a centimeter, so there are 25.4 mm in an inch, which would mean that there should be 96/25.4 px/mm = 3.779527559055...  However, if you convert in the other direction, and say that there are 1/2.54 inches in a centimeter, you are going to have some rounding shenanigans, because 1/2.54 is not a nice, clean decimal.  So then depending on how you round that value, you will get slightly different answers down the road.

Comment: Combine this with the general messiness of double arithmetic in most languages, and I'm not surprised there are some subtle differences.  But I won't pretend to know the exact internal implementation that is causing these differences.

Comment: [mm is for print[](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

Comment: Yes, Rob, mm is for print.